# Background processing for long running queries via RODBC in R

Tags: r, rodbc

Is it possible to avoid locking the R session while waiting for a RODBC query to finish execution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **future** package provides asynchronous processing

https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future

```
library(future)
plan(multiprocess())
v %<-% {
  rnorm(10^8) %>% summary
}
print("Not locked, waiting for v to calculate")
```